# Create an anchor link in Java Tapestry using t:pagelink and context

Tags: java, templates, tapestry

I can create a link to a page using this .tml code. This generates a link to eg "/path/case314":

```
<t:pagelink page="${pageName}" t:context="case">
linked text                             
</t:pagelink>
```

I want to create a path to eg "/path/case314#comment-id-90".

If I try to direct my link to an anchor within a page, like so (where there is a div of id #comment-id-${currentComment.id} in the targeted page):

```
<t:pagelink page="${pageName}#comment-id-${currentComment.id}" t:context="case">
linked text                             
</t:pagelink>
```

Then I lose my context, and I get the default pageName path, like so: "/path/caseexample#comment-id-90". Which doesn't exist, so Tapestry throws an exception.

The same thing happens if I try to create a class manually constructing the link- passing pageName as a parameter results in "caseexample" rather than the correct "case314".

Can anyone tell me how I can build an anchor link while maintaining the necessary context for the pagelink to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<t:pagelink page="prop:pageName" anchor="comment-id-${currentComment.id}" context="case">linked text</t:pagelink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, see [there](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/PageLink.html) for the list of parameters available for the pagelink component.

You'll see the "anchor" param used by uklance.